# How to add if condition in express validation 6

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I want to add the if condition in express validation 6

Like:-
if one form user_type field value is "kid_user" then validation apply on like("dob") field and if user_type field value is "teens_user" then validation not apply on dob field.

Answer (score 0):

Express Validator has a feature called

> oneOf

You can provide an array of validations into this feature and if one of the validation passes, it will return success. For your case, the code might look like this:

```
oneOf([
      [
        check("user_type").equals("kid_user"),
        check("age").isFloat({ min: 2, max: 10 }),
      ],
      [
        check("user_type").equals("teen_user"),
        check("age").isFloat({ min: 11, max: 19 }),
      ],
    ]),
```

If you are more interested into condition, you can take a look [here](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/releases/tag/v6.1.0)

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it not working

Comment: Did you check all the spellings and values? I used teen_user here, but in your post teens_user was used.